# Laplace equation with initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, elliptic-equations

So I have Laplace equation:

$$ u_{xx}+u_{yy}= 0 $$

and initial conditions

$$ u(0,y)=0, \;\: u_x(0,y)=y  $$

And I have to solve it.

**My solution:**

If we assume that the solution is of the form:  $$ u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y) $$

Then follows: $$ u(0,y)=X(0)Y(y)=0; \:\; u_x(0,y)=X'(0)Y(y)=y.$$
Furthermore: $$ u_{xx}(x,y)=X''(x)Y(y); \:\; u_{yy}(x,y)=X(x)Y''(y) $$
From that, we get: $$ \begin{aligned}&\;u_{xx}+u_{yy}=X''(x)Y(y)+X(x)Y''(y)=0 \\ \\\Leftrightarrow& \; X''(x)Y(y)=-X(x)Y''(y)  \\\\
 \Leftrightarrow& \; -\frac{X(x)}{X''(x)}=\frac{Y(y)}{Y''(y)}  \end{aligned}$$

**My problem:**
Every time I try to go further I get:
$X(0)=0$, which then implies, that $X'(0)=0$, which furthermore is in contradiction with $X'(0)Y(y)=y$

This is a part where I didn't know where to go further, everything I try to insert doesn't end well and I am not sure, whether my approach was good at all. I would appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: You are missing both the domain and two boundary conditions, pretty important pieces of information.

Comment: Our Professor formulated the question like I have written it without any additional information. Just initial conditions and that's all. And that was actually the first time this equation was mentioned... So it's not possible to do it without then?

Comment: Well, no. Separation of variables yields two _second order_ ODEs, which implies you need four boundary conditions to get an explicit solution. You have specified two, both of which occur at the same boundary. If the problem from your lecturer was 'Solve ...' as you have given it, then I'm not really sure what they are expecting, especially if they haven't told you the domain. Maybe they want you to use a Fourier or Laplace transform? In which case they would need to specify the domain.

Comment: @variableXYZ Why $X(0)=0$ implies $X'(0)=0$ (as you said in your post)? This is not correct.

Comment: @mattos In this particular case we have only *one* second order ODE because $Y(y)$ is obtained from the given initial condition. Therefore, it's possible to use separation of variables.

Comment: @epiliam We do not need a "complete" boundary condition. See my previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your calculation, we have to solve
$$(1)\left\{\begin{aligned}&X''+\lambda X=0\\
&X(0)=0\end{aligned}\right.\qquad\text{and}\qquad 
(2)\left\{\begin{aligned}&Y''-\lambda Y=0\\
&Y(y)=ky
\end{aligned}\right.$$
where $\lambda$ and $k=(X'(0))^{-1}$ are constants.

The nonzero solutions of $(1)$ are

$$X(x)=\left\{\begin{aligned}
&c_1\sin(\sqrt{\lambda} x),\quad&&\text{if } \lambda>0\\
&c_1e^{\sqrt{-\lambda} x}-c_1e^{-\sqrt{-\lambda} x},\quad&&\text{if } \lambda<0\\
& c_1 x, \quad&&\text{if } \lambda=0
\end{aligned}\right.\tag{3}$$

with $c_1\neq 0$. From system $(2)$, we have
$$Y(y)=ky\quad \Rightarrow \quad Y'(y)=k\quad \Rightarrow \quad Y''(y)=0\quad \Rightarrow \quad \lambda=0.$$

Thus, the only possibility is the third case of $(3)$:
$$X(x)=c_1 x,\qquad  Y(y)=ky=(X'(0))^{-1}y=\frac{1}{c_1} y.$$
and the desired solution is
$$u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)=(c_1 x)\left(\frac{1}{c_1}y\right)=xy.$$

Answer (score 1):

Of course, only inspection is sufficient to find the solution $u(x,y)=xy$ ( through trial and error). I suppose that the question is how analytically ? They are several methods. For example :

It is well known that the general solution of
$$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0\tag 1$$
can be expressed on the form :
$$u(x,y)=F(y+ix)+G(y-ix)\tag 2$$
in which $F$ and $G$ are arbitrary complex functions in the most general case.

The conditions considered here are :
$$u(0,y)=F(y)+G(y)=0\quad\implies\quad F'(y)+G'(y)=0$$
$$u_x(0,y)=iF'(y)-iG'(y))=y$$
Solving for $F'$ leads to :
$$F'(y)=-\frac{i}{2}y$$
Integrating wrt $y$ leads to :
$$F(y)=-\frac{i}{4}y^2+c$$
$$G(y)=-F(y)=\frac{i}{4}y^2-c$$
Now the functions $F$ and $G$ are known. We put them into Eq.$(2)$ where the variables are not $y$ but are $(y+ix)$ and $(y-ix)$ respectively.
$$u=\left(-\frac{i}{4}(y+ix)^2+c\right)+\left(\frac{i}{4}(y-ix)^2-c\right)$$
Expend and simplify. The result is :
$$u(x,y)=xy$$

Answer (score 0):

After a little tinkering with multilinear functions, I found a solution to be $u(x,y)=xy$.

Comment: Could you explain how did you reach that solution?

Comment: @variableXYZ We can use separation of variables. The work is almost done in your post. See the details in my answer.